# SOAP-request realization in DOS 6.22 16-bit

Tags: curl

I have a task to develop some application providing SOAP-requests realization for DOS. I have already developed a similar application under Linux, using C++/STL and curl and openssl libraries. Is there any way to use such method in my environment now? The environment is DOS 6.22, 16bit, open watcom compiler, access to the Internet. How do I install curl and openssl in Dos?Is it possible? Are there any other ways for SOAP-requests realization in DOS? Thanks in advance!